# Can a Windows Store app consume a WCF service that uses Entity Framework 5?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a WCF service that is built using EF5.  The service to returns a collection of objects that are defined in the EF model.  But since I can't use EF within the Windows Store app I'm thinking this isn't possible.  If this is the case, what's the best option for consuming the service from a Windows Store App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objects are POCO objects then you should be able to use them in your Window Store Application as they don't need to have any references to Entity Framework assemblies. Ideally they would live in a separate assembly that you could reference from both - your service and your Windows Store App. If your entities are not POCO entities (i.e. are derived from the EntityObject class) then ideally you move away from this solution (new EF5 apps will create POCO entities though).